# java remove timezone offset from timestamp

Tags: java, timestamp

I have XMLGregorianCalendar date like this '2016-09-27T10:49:27.640+03:00'
needed get timestams without timezone offset 
I do this:

```
XMLGregorianCalendar gcWorkDate = request.getWorkDate();
//gcWorkDate = (com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl) 2016-09-27T10:49:27.640+03:00
gcWorkDate.setTimezone(0);
//gcWorkDate = (com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl) 2016-09-27T10:49:27.640Z
Timestamp tsWorkDate = new Timestamp(gcWorkDate.toGregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis());
//tsWorkDate = (java.sql.Timestamp) 2016-09-27 13:49:27.64
```

I want to receive tsWorkDate = 2016-09-27 10:49:27.64
What I doing wrong?

Comment: Try using [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for `tsWorkDate`

Answer (score 1):

do this.

```
setTimezone(DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED);
```